# Swup with svg xlink

Tags: html, svg, xlink, swup

I can't get Swap to work with xlinks.

I tried to create page transitions with Swup. Things work ok with normal `<a href="/secondpage.html">` tags, but inside svg I need to use `<a xlink:href="/secondpage.html">`.

From Swup documentation I found that xlinks should work as a selectors.

```
'LINK_SELECTOR: 'a[href^="/"]:not([data-no-swup]), a[href^="#"]:not([data-no-swup]), a[xlink\\:href]'
```

Any ideas on how to get Swup to work with SVG xlinks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out already? For xlink in svg files use:

```
svg a[*|href]
```

So:

```
linkSelector: 'a[href^="/"]:not([data-no-swup]), a[href^="#"]:not([data-no-swup]), asvg a[*|href]'
```

Credit goes to daun on the Swup github.